# Importing CSV file into SQL using PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to import a `CSV` file into my `SQL` database. This is what I have:

```
if ($_FILES[csvFile][size] > 0)
{ 
$file = $_FILES[csvFile][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

do { 
    if ($data[0]) 
    { 

    $insert_query = "REPLACE INTO `teacherNames` SET 
    `schoolName` = '".addslashes($schoolname)."',
    `teacherName` = '".addslashes($data[0])."'
    ;";  

        $result = mysql_query($insert_query);
        echo $insert_query; -- SEE RESULTING QUERY BELOW
        echo $data[0]." added\n<br />";
    } 
} 
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

The `CSV` file has 3 records and it looks correct. The procedure works to an extent but for some reason it is not reading the `CSV` file correctly and the resulting query is like this:

```
REPLACE INTO `teacherNames` SET `schoolName` = 'Brooks', `teacherName` = 'RMG JMC PMC';
```

When I would expect to get 3 separate queries - one for each record. It does not seem to be reading the `CSV` file as 3 separate records but as 1. Can anyone see why?

UPDATE:

The CSV contents are:

```
RMG
JMC
PMC
```

Comment: csv contents would also help :)

Comment: `$data` will be null the first time through your loop because you're using a do/while - the `while` part of the expression isn't evaluated until one full time through the loop.

Comment: the csv is really separated by commas?? You can open the file and then explode ";"

Comment: @JulioMarins there does appear to be a CSV issue. I created it in Excel (for the Mac) and then copied it. The new copy does not work but it looks the same in Excel and a text editor. Strange.

Comment: Why do you want to use REPLACE at all? Is (schoolName, teachername) primary key?

Comment: @VMai Good question - but I have removed the key for ease of reading on here. That bit works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anwer of Julio Martins is better if you have the file on the same computer as the MySQL server.

But if you need to read the file from inside the PHP, there is a note from PHP.NET at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php :

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading
>   files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help
>   resolve the problem.

How is the line endings on your file? As all lines are being read as one, it can be your case i guess.

To turn auto_detect_line_endings on, use `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` as said Pistachio at http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#107333

Comment: That is superb - just the job. Thanks so much. Added that line and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

Use while instead do-while:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does the same.

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the CSV file itself. If I create it again it seems to work. Maybe a Mac Excel thing.

Comment: Look toward line breaks of your CSV file.

Comment: Is there any way of telling?

Comment: Look at this: http://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-04-30-excel-and-line-endings/
"On a Mac, Excel produces csv files with the wrong line endings, which causes problems for git (amongst other things)."
It is possible, that fgetcsv() can't detect line endings properly from your CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Try load data:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '{$filepath}'
INTO TABLE '{$table}'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

It is cleaner

Comment: If he can use this query it is indeed better. But he is using `,` as field separator on the `while` line (your code uses `;`) and all lines must be read (your code ignores the first one). Trivial, but fixing it to the question needs won't hurt.